# List comprehension guard equivalent of filterM

Tags: haskell

List comprehensions have overlapping functionality with `map` and `filter`. `filterM` caters for the situation in which the predicate returns a `Bool` wrapped in a monad (well, an Applicative, to be precise). `mapM` does something similar for mapping functions whose result is wrapped in an Applicative.

In case you want to reproduce the behaviour of `mapM` with a list comprehension, `sequence` comes to the rescue. But how can `filterM` be replaced with a list comprehension? In other words, how can a predicate which returns a `Bool` inside a context, be used as a guard in list comprehensions?

Below are trivial examples exploring the 2x2x2 space (**f**ilter/**m**ap, **f**unction/**c**omprehension, **p**lain/**m**onadic) of above observations, only I don't know how to write `fcm`. How can `fcm` be fixed so that it has the same value as `ffm`?

```
import Control.Monad (filterM)

predicate = (>3)
convert = (*10)
predicateM = Just . predicate -- Just represents an arbitrary monad
convertM   = Just . convert
data_ = [1..5]

ffp = filter           predicate  data_
ffm = filterM          predicateM data_
fcp = [a | a <- data_, predicate  a]
fcm = [a | a <- data_, predicateM a]

mfp = map        convert           data_
mfm = mapM       convertM          data_
mcp =          [ convert  a | a <- data_ ]
mcm = sequence [ convertM a | a <- data_ ]
```

## Edit:

It's important to note that the versions whose name ends in `m` must use a `convertM` or `predicateM`: the plain `convert` and `predicate` are unavailable in those situations; that's the whole point of the question.

## Background information

The motivation arises from having a bunch of functions (here is a simplified collection, which is hopefully representative)

```
convert   ::  a  -> r -> b
predicate ::  a  -> r -> Bool
big       :: [a] -> r -> [b]

big as r = [ convert a r | a <- as, predicate a r ]
```

which are begging to be refactored in terms of Reader ... and one of which (`big`) uses one of the others (`predicate`) as a predicate in listcomp guard.

Refactoring works just fine, as long as the listcomp is replaced with a combination of `mapM` and `filterM`:

```
convertR   ::  a  -> Reader r b
predicateR ::  a  -> Reader r Bool
bigR       :: [a] -> Reader r [b]

bigR as = mapM convertR =<< filterM predicateR as
```

The trouble with this is that, in real life, the listcomp is much more complex, and the translation to `mapM` and `filterM` is far less clean.

Hence the motivation for wanting to keep the listcomp even when the predicate has turned monadic.

## Edit 2

The real listcomp is more complex, because it combines elements from more than one list. I've tried to extact the essence of the problem into the following example, which differs from Edit 1 in that

- The listcomp in `big` takes data from more than one list.
- `predicate` takes more than one value as input.
- `convert` has been rename to `combine` and takes more than one value as input.
- Similar changes for the `Reader` versions.

.

```
combine   :: r -> (a,a) -> b
predicate :: r -> (a,a) -> Bool
big, big' :: r -> [a]   -> [b]

big  r as = [ combine r (a,b) | a <- as, b <- as, predicate r (a,b) ]
big' r as = map (combine r) $ filter (predicate r) $ [ (a,b) | a <- as, b <- as ]

combineR    :: (a,a) -> Reader r b
predicateR  :: (a,a) -> Reader r Bool
bigR, bigR' :: [a]   -> Reader r [b]

bigR     = undefined
bigR' as = mapM combineR =<< filterM predicateR =<< return [ (a,b) | a <- as, b <- as ]
```

`big'` is a rewrite of `big` in which `combine` and `predicate` are extracted from the listcomp. This has a direct equivalent in the Reader version: `bigR'`. So, the question is, how can you write `bigR` which should be

1. Not significantly uglier than `bigR'`
2. As direct a translation of `big` as reasonably possible.

At this stage I'm tempted to conclude that `bigR'` is as good as it's going to get. This implies that the answer to my question is:

- keep the listcomp for constructing the cartesian product
- move `predicate` and `combine` out of the expression into a `filter` and a `map` respectively
- in the monadic version, replace `filter` and `map` with `filterM` and `mapM` (and `$` with `=<<`).
- uncurry the predicate and combiner functions: the listcomp works equally well with curried and uncurried versions, but the map-filter combination needs them to be curried. At this stage this is probably the biggest price to pay for losing the ability to use the listcomp.

Comment: isn't it just `fcm = Just [a | a <- data_, predicate a]`? (It can't result in a `Nothing` because `(Just . predicate)` doesn't ever.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond The `m` in `fcm` indicates that the predicate returns `m Bool`. By changing `(Just . predicate)` to `predicate` you've moved from the `fcm` corner of the cube to the `fcp` corner. The whole point is that, for whatever reason, the predicate returns a monad, and I don't have the option of changing that, I just have to deal with it. (In real life this came up when refactoring a bunch of functions into the Reader monad, and suddenly my predicate turned monadic and my lisctomp broke.)

Comment: but a predicate by definition cannot return `m Bool`. It must return a `Bool`. You're thinking of the fact that the function argument to `filterM` is of type `a -> m Bool`, but you can't use that in a list comprehension because it's not actually a predicate. I thought the aim for `fcm` was for it to produce the same result as `ffm` but using a list comp - what I've put above is the only way I see to do it.

Comment: @RobinZigmond As I said, this is motivated by refactoring to Reader. Imagine you have `fcm :: [a] -> r -> [b]` and `p :: a -> r -> Bool`. `fcm a r = [ xxx a r | a <- as , p a r]. Then you try to refactor to `fcm :: [a] -> Reader r [b]` and `p :: a -> Reader r Bool`, which makes `p` unusable in the listcomp. Changing `xxx` from `a -> r ->b` to `a -> Reader r b` can be dealt with *either* by switching to `mapM` or using `sequence` with the listcomp. I can see how to deal with the change in `p` by replacing the listcomp with `filterM`, but can it be done without getting rid of the listcomp?

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yes, `fcm` is supposed to produce the same result as `ffm` using a listcomp ... **while respecting the fact that the only function you had to supply `filterM` has type `a -> m Bool`**. `(Just . predicate)` represents the function I have to work with. I do not have the luxury of removing the `Just .`

Comment: I see. In that case, while I'm relatively new to Haskell and hesitant to say "you can't", I just can't see how you can do this. Your `mcm` version simply takes advantage of the fact that `mapM f` is equal to `sequence . (map f)`. I don't think there is any similar identity relating `filterM` to `filter`. Crucially, you can's use a function of type `a -> m Bool` as the predicate inside a list comprehension, whereas it's fine to use a function `a -> m b` as the output function.

Comment: If there's a way to do it, I suspect it will involve the `MonadComprehensions` extension. I'm playing with it now, will update later.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I can't figure out a way to do it with *just* a list comp, but this might get you closer? (I've listed some intermediate steps I went through so you can take it in a different direction if you need).

```
{-# LANGUAGE MonadComprehensions #-}

predicateM = return . (>3)
[[a | True <- predicateM a] | a <- [1,2,3,4,5]] 
  :: (Num b, Ord b, Control.Monad.Fail.MonadFail m) => [m b]
[[if b then Just a else Nothing | b <- predicateM a] | a <- [1,2,3,4,5]]
  :: (Num a, Monad m, Ord a) => [m (Maybe a)]
[[bool Nothing (Just a) b | b <- predicateM a] | a <- [1,2,3,4,5]]
  :: (Num a, Monad m, Ord a) => [m (Maybe a)]
catMaybes <$> sequence [[bool Nothing (Just a) b | b <- predicateM a] | a <- [1,2,3,4,5]]
  :: (Monad f, Num a, Ord a) => f [a]

filterM' p xs = catMaybes <$> sequence [[bool Nothing (Just a) b | b <- p a] | a <- xs]
```

There may be something neater with a `ListT`?

EDIT: Another approach, although it spews some warnings about `ListT` giving unlawful instances..

```
unListT (ListT x) = x
filterM'' p xs = unListT [a | (a,True) <- ListT $ mapM (\x -> return . (x,) =<< p x) xs]
```

EDIT2: Okay I got it down to a single comprehension!

```
filterM''' :: (Traversable m1, Monad m2, Monad m1, Alternative m1) => (b -> m2 Bool) -> m1 b -> m2 (m1 b)
filterM''' p xs = [[a | (a,b) <- mlist, b] | mlist <- mapM (\x -> return . (x,) =<< p x) xs]
```

EDIT3: Another approach, because I'm not sure on precisely what you need access to.

```
filterM' p xs = [x | x <- filterM p xs]
```

Then, nest the comprehensions to obtain access to the "inner" element type eg. filtering and mapping,

```
filterMap f p xs = [[f x | x <- mlist] | mlist <- filterM p xs]
```

Comment: I've added another edit, to emphasize the pragmatic motivation behind this. The point isn't to force it into a listcomp for the hell of it (fun and interesting though that may be!) In my edit you can see that the listcomp uses multiple input sets, and that there is a very clean translation to map+filter, which has a very clean translation to the monadic version, but it comes at the cost of having to uncurry the predicate and combiner. So the big-picture question is: is there a way of wirting it as a listcomp that is neater than the uncurry-`filterM`-`mapM` approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader
import Control.Monad (filterM)
```

The question was motivated by the desire to take some functions of the form

```
f ::  x  ->  y  ->  z ->   a                 ; f  = undefined
p ::  x  ->  y  ->  z -> Bool                ; p  = undefined
u :: [x] -> [y] -> [z] -> [a]
```

and replace them with similar ones within some context (`Reader` in this example):

```
fR ::  x  ->  y  ->  z  -> Reader r  a        ; fR = undefined
pR ::  x  ->  y  ->  z  -> Reader r Bool      ; pR = undefined
uR :: [x] -> [y] -> [z] -> Reader r [a]
```

At the core of the question, one of the original functions has a multi-input list comprehension that uses the other functions for combining and filtering purposes:

```
u xs ys zs = [ f x y z | x <- xs, y <- ys, z <- zs, p x y z ]
```

The question addresses the difficulties of implementing the equivalent, contextful, `uR` function; specifically the apparent loss of ability to use a list comprehension and its conveniences.

There is a fairly neat translation of `u` into an implementation that combines a list comprehension, `filter` and `map`. This is shown as `u'` below. `u'` has a direct translation to the contextful version, `uR`:

```
u' xs ys zs = map  ucf  $   filter  ucp  $           cartesian xs ys zs
uR xs ys zs = mapM ucfR =<< filterM ucpR =<< return (cartesian xs ys zs)
```

In the above, the list comprehension is packed up in `cartesian`

```
cartesian xs ys zs = [ (x,y,z) | x <- xs, y <- ys, z <- zs ]
```

and the solution requires the original functions (`p`, `f`, `pR` and `fR`) to be uncurried:

```
ucp = uncurry3 p     ;    ucpR = uncurry3 pR
ucf = uncurry3 f     ;    ucfR = uncurry3 fR

uncurry3 :: (a -> b -> c -> r) -> (a, b, c) -> r
uncurry3 f = \(a,b,c) -> f a b c
```

Maybe this solution can be sugared with a monad comprehension, but I haven't the time to think about that right now.

Comment: Sorry, the reason I wrote a few different versions was because I was experimenting myself and also because I wasn't exactly sure on your requirements. You have a few options, `uR xs ys zs = sequence [ join [ fR x y z | True <- pR x y z ] | x <- xs, y <- ys, z <- zs ]` is one of the clearer. You could remove the join by complicating the inner comprehension, and/or you can change the MonadFail constraint to Alternative by matching on the Bool directly ..`[ r | r <- fR x y z, p <- pR x y z, p]` (here both changes demonstrated). You may still feel the non-comprehension versions clearer though!